# Media query font setting not working on `360` screen width

Tags: html, css

Basically, I am resetting all my `font-size` to work with all screen sizes. basically i am resetting to `10px`.

the issue is, one of the query i am using here:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        font: normal 2.083333333333333vw/1 normal sans-serif;
    }
}
```

Is not giving correct output to `360` screen size. since above sets from `321` to `480` - but not setting with `360` screen.

what is the wrong here?

Here is my full resetting to `10px` to all view ports.

```
p {
    font-size: 1.2em; //in all media it will be 12px.
}



@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    body {
        font: normal 3.125vw/1 normal sans-serif;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        font: normal 2.083333333333333vw/1 normal sans-serif;
    }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 640px) {
    body {
        font: normal 1.5625vw/1 normal sans-serif;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        font: normal 1.305483028720627vw/1 normal sans-serif;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
    body {
        font: normal 1vw/1 normal sans-serif;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

What i expect is : whatever the view port size, the `min-font size` should be `10px`.example (320px) and more than this view-port the `font-size` should be maxium `14px`. how to make this?

Comment: Are you saying it's not going in here?
`@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px)`

Comment: have you tired other widths?

Comment: What devices, what browsers? Also, I think just setting the font size to 10px might be easier.

Comment: actually, i am wrong here i guess. in case desktop show me `10px` for `1em` then i need to reduce the `font-size` according to the view-ports. or what is the correct way to calculate the font size according to the view ports

Comment: Where are you looking at this at 360? On the actual device or browser resolution?

Comment: @3gwebtrain It's less and less obvious what you are trying to do. If the font size needs to be 10px, then just make it 10px. If it needs to depend on the viewport size, then _don't_ try to make it 10px. And I can't duplicate the issue: on a narrow screen, the text works as expected.

Comment: Yeah, are you trying to make it scale between viewport sizes? please articulate your end goal!!!!!!!!!!